# SDL crashes itself and other windows

Tags: c++, linux, sdl, kde-plasma

I've written small sdl application. Problem is that is crashes almost everything when I launch it. Every window loses title bar. Application sometimes pops up, sometimes doesn't. If it does, pressing q (key for quitting) closes it but other windows remains 'broken'. Only way to get rid of this is to logout and then log in again.
Here's code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

const int screen_x = 800;
const int screen_y = 600;

SDL_Window* window = nullptr;
SDL_Texture* textures[3];
SDL_Texture* currentTexture = nullptr;
SDL_Renderer* renderer = nullptr;
SDL_Event event;

bool running = true;

SDL_Texture* loadTexture(const char* path)
{
    SDL_Texture* texture = nullptr;
    SDL_Surface* load = IMG_Load(path);
    if (!load)
    {
        printf("Failed to load image %s. Error: %s\n", path, IMG_GetError());
    }
    else
    {
        texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, load);
        if (!texture)
        {
            printf("Failed to convert surface from %s. Error: %s\n", path, SDL_GetError());
        }

        SDL_FreeSurface(load);
    }

    return texture;
}

bool loadMedia()
{
    bool success = true;

    currentTexture = textures[0] = loadTexture("./img/1.png");
    if (!textures[0])
    {
        printf("Failed to load texture\n");
        success = false;
    }

    textures[1] = loadTexture("./img/2.png");
    if (!textures[1])
    {
        printf("Failed to load texture\n");
        success = false;
    }

    textures[2] = loadTexture("./img/3.png");
    if (!textures[2])
    {
        printf("Failed to load texture\n");
        success = false;
    }

    return success;
}

bool init()
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0)
    {
        printf("Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL with linux", 0, 0, screen_x, screen_y, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if (!window)
        {
            printf("Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
            if (!renderer)
            {
                printf("Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
                int imgFlags = IMG_INIT_PNG;
                if ((IMG_Init(imgFlags) & imgFlags) != imgFlags)
                {
                    printf("Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

void close()
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        SDL_DestroyTexture(textures[i]);
        textures[i] = nullptr;
    }
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    renderer = nullptr;
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    window = nullptr;
    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (!init())
    {
        printf("Initialization error\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if (!loadMedia())
        {
            printf("Media loading error\n");
        }
        else
        {

            while (running)
            {
                while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
                {
                    switch (event.type)
                    {
                        case SDL_QUIT:
                            running = false;
                            break;

                        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                            switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
                            {
                                case SDLK_q:
                                    running = false;
                                    break;

                                case SDLK_1:
                                    currentTexture = textures[0];
                                    break;

                                case SDLK_2:
                                    currentTexture = textures[1];
                                    break;

                                case SDLK_3:
                                    currentTexture = textures[2];
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
                SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
                SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, currentTexture, nullptr, nullptr);
                SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
                SDL_Delay(80);
            }
        }
    }
    close();
    return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
CC = g++
CFlags = -Wall -std=c++11
Input = main.cpp
Output = -o ./bin/prog
Linker = -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2_mixer

all:
    $(CC) $(Input) $(CFlags) $(Linker) $(Output)
```

Screenshot showing behavior of application

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry this is going to be more like a comment but i dont have 50 reputation to comment in questions . Can you provide a screenshot of the window?
If not then try using SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED at the x and y axis then see if the window is showing up. Please share if this worked